# Trouble understanding how to use the chain rule to compute $(n \circ \gamma)'(0)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, chain-rule

I'm reading about the Gauss map. $\gamma(t)=r(u(t),v(t))$ is a curve along a surface and $n$ the map that sends the normal vectors in the curve to the sphere. I've seen the following manipulation:

$$n\circ \gamma (t) = n \circ r(u(t),v(t))$$

And hence:

$$(n \circ \gamma)'(0)=u' n_u + v' n_v$$

where $n_u= (n\circ r)_u$ and $n_v= (n\circ r)_v$.

*Question:* I understand that they are using the chain rule in there, but I am confused at what is going on in there. Could you expand a little bit more?

Comment: WHich normal are you referring? The normal of the surface or normal of the curve itself (in tangent plane)? Also malayali anno o_o

Comment: Also maybe saying soruce will help you find a good answer

Comment: @Buraian Normal to the surface, I guess.

Comment: What exactly are you confused on? If you want more details, you could think $\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} \frac{\partial}{ \partial u } + \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \frac{\partial }{\partial v}$, the LHS and RHS is vector. What you got is the corresponding tangent vector on the sphere as you move along the curve on the surrface

Comment: To be more precise, you should have $u'(0)$, $v'(0)$, and $n_u(u(0),v(0))$, $n_v(u(0),v(0))$. Remember that your text's convention is that $n=n(u,v)$ is the surface normal at the point $r(u,v)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, It's still not clear to me how to compute that.

Comment: Look up in your calculus book the derivative of $f(u(t),v(t))$ with respect to $t$. Actually, your text is *not* quite doing what I said. They are considering $n$ as a function on the surface (which is quite common), but writing, as they said, $n_u$ to indicate $(n\circ r)_u$.  So we're applying the general chain rule with $f(u,v) = (n\circ r)(u,v)$ but writing $f_u = n_u$ (which is common, but confusing). (In my differential geometry text, I write the correct notation $D_{r_u}n$ for the derivative of $n$ (as function on the surface) in the direction of the tangent vector $r_u$.)